# Tensorflow TFLearn working example

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm approaching to the world of deep learning, and the framework that I'm using is Tensorflow. In order to start quickly, I've seen that there are high level api called TFLearn, wich makes the creation of a network a lot easier. Unfortunaly, there are no working examples. In particular, I'm trying this example:

[Example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/extending_tensorflow/layers.py)

but it can't find the layers. I've tried to import tflearn in this way:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as tflearn
```

and the dataset in this way

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist as mnist
```

and they works, but I'm still not able to use the layers.

***EDIT***

I also tried to import in this way (as reported on tflearn github page):

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn as tflearn
```

and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn' has no attribute 'conv_2d'
```

What can I do?

Comment: You mean these examples don't work? http://tflearn.org/tutorials/ http://tflearn.org/examples/ See Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj0iyo265bc

Comment: Yes, those example don't work. It's strange because the example I linked was updated 20 day ago. I have a doubt: should I install tflearn with pip also if I have tensorflow 12.0.1? Should't it be in the contrib folder?

Comment: tf.contrib.learn / tf.learn is part of TensorFlow, and has no relation to tflearn.org or the tflearn Python package. Just an unfortunate name collision.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)"`?

Comment: @MartinThoma It's 0.12.1.

Comment: @AllenLavoie oh, I understand. This is very unclear, and leads (like in this case) to strange situations. By the way, I think I'll move on Keras!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as tflearn
```

Instead install tflearn in your terminal, using installation guide http://tflearn.org/installation/

Then, import like:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
```

This way you can use the layers.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet some strange errors with TFlearn... it seems it is not properly maintained and updated, so now it is not in sync with Tensorflow...